# Is there a way to include multiple attributes inside a bracket selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a way to shorten these lines of code and not repeat myself, since they do the same thing?

```
.my-form input[type="text"]{
    padding: 8px;
    width: 100%;
}
.my-form input[type="email"]{
    padding: 8px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: comma separated selectors?

Comment: yes, something like .my-form input[type="text","email"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides removing the "[type=...]" as Abdul Hannan suggested, the only shorter way I can think of to express this would be the following:

```
.my-form input[type="text"],
.my-form input[type="email"]{
    padding: 8px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Yes! This works just fine. I never saw using multiple selectors like this. Will look more into it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. If the only input fields are text and email then you can simply set your code in 
   .my-form input {//code here}.
2. The best way to go about this would be to use a CSS Preprocessor such as SASS. It would help in achieving such re-usability in code.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but there are multiple other input fields. These are the only that I want those attributes applied.

Comment: Then the best method would be to use SASS. If you haven't use it already, this maybe a nice chance for you to explore about SASS. Its super easy and makes life easier with CSS